# Sample size in genome-wide studies

Tags: genetics, statistical-power

How to calculate sample size needed for GWAS for a given MAF, power, $p$-value and frequency of the disease ?

Comment: I assume GWAS is a genome-wide association study, but what is MAF?

Comment: @Simon MAF stands for minor allele frequency.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it myself, but you might like to try the [GWApower](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~marchini/software.html#GWApower) R package. See [Spencer *et al.* 2009](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pgen.1000477).

Comment: (+1) I also have this one in my list, [Power analysis for genome-wide association studies](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2156/8/58).